# Trigger success with compilation error oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl

I have these tables

```
PUBRED (cod_pub, title, year, type, medium)
AUTHOR (login, name, surname, institution, country)
AUTHOR_ONE (login, cod_pub)
PUB_CITA (cod_pub, cod_pub_cited)
```

And I have to get that citations to a publication should always be after it

I have the following trigger but it gives me compilation errors and I don't find any errors looking in other questions

```
Create or replace trigger works_trg_02
Before insert or update on pub_cita
For each row
Declare
Cnt number;
Begin
Select count (*) into cnt
      from pubred pr
      inner join pub_cita pc
         on :new.pc.cod_pub = pr.cod_pub
      inner join pubred pr2
         on :new.pc.cod_pub_cited = pr2.cod_pub
      where pr.year < pr2.year then 1
Else 0 end = 0;
If cnt <> 0 then
Raise_application_error ('-20001', 'Not possible');
End if;
End works_trg_02;
/
```

I get the typical error from 'ORA-24344: success with compilation error'

And when doing the inserts to prove it I get 'ORA-04098: trigger 'FIDDLE_WIXYFBGEUZDXILZQBEGR.WORKS_TRG_02' is invalid and failed re-validation'

I have searched other similar questions that have been asked around here adapting my initial solution and I have not been successful and I believe that everything there is is correct.

Comment: This part `where pr.year < pr2.year then 1
Else 0 end = 0;` does not make any sense. Apart from that, you cannot select from `pub_cita` inside a trigger for the same table `pub_cita`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you get `ORA-24344: success with compilation error`, you should run `show errors`, or query the `user_errors` or `all_errors` views to find your actual error message.

Second, this is wrong: `:new.pc.cod_pub`. The `:new` variable is a `record`, the row of the table (`pub_cita`) currently being inserted. You can just say `:new.cod_pub`.

Third, a trigger can't query its own table - so you can't have `pub_cita` in your SELECT query. Which is fine, you can refer to it using `:new`.

Fourth, what is this?

```
where pr.year < pr2.year then 1
Else 0 end = 0;
```

I think you started a `CASE` statement, then deleted part of it? It's not valid syntax.

See if this works for you:

```
Create or replace trigger works_trg_02
Before insert or update on pub_cita
For each row
Declare
    Cnt number;
Begin
    Select count (*) into cnt
          from pubred pr
          inner join pubred pr2
             on :new.cod_pub_cited = pr2.cod_pub
          where pr.year < pr2.year
            and pr.cod_pub = :new.cod_pub
          ;
    If cnt <> 0 then
        Raise_application_error ('-20001', 'Not possible');
    End if;
End works_trg_02;
/
```